# Writing a beautiful website with ads - is it possible?

Tags: ads

I'm just starting to create a website that supports my business.  I want a sleek design oriented site - because that's what I like and it also suits my business.

Trouble is that all the mocks looks terrible once I start to incorporate Ads into the site.  (My ad provider will most likely be Google AdSense - if that matters).

Has anyone seen a beautiful / design oriented website that incorporates ads?  Are there any coding tricks to make the ads less in your face.

Thanks!

*PS: if this is the wrong forum please let me know...*

Comment: wrong site -- try doctype.com

Comment: Considering that the content of the ads is something thats completely out of your control, i dont really see how you can prevent it from potentially ruining the aesthetic feel of your page. If its a website that just supports your business and is not really a direct revenue stream but maybe more of an indirect one, i would re-consider the decision to have ads on it in the first place.

Comment: @InSane: Have been considering this very question long and hard.  I would like to earn a penny here and there, that's part of the point of the site.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Fair enough. I have yet to see any beautiful design oriented site - which continued to look that way - with ads. Will track this question. Maybe someone else might have.

Comment: Are you saying Stack Overflow isn't beautiful? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to put ads in areas that people use for functionality. So dont put ads all over the front, landing page.

Put the ads on the search results page or pages of the like. The people on that page are actively looking for something so they are more inclined to see your ad even if its already in your face.

So my opinion is strategically placed ads!

Comment: also rss emails with ads in them. be creative!

Comment: rss email ads, that's clever.

Comment: so where is strategically placed?  Right side?  Off screen?  Have you seen sites that do place ads well? Thanks!

Comment: i know of a few, but majority of the time, the websites that i think have good design with ads only have a few ads. Ads for me are placed in the areas that i mentioned, "strategically". 
i think this site is good compared to others:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design-blog/

this website incorporates the design of the site all over the ads, which i like. 
http://css-tricks.com/

like i said be creative. If you not sure where to put ads, put them in the pages i recommended.

Comment: also if your a coder, use that to your advantage. if your a designer, use that. Lean on what your good at. its all about creativity. :] you will figure out where is a good spot and how to design around them

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a webpage in which I felt that ADs were incorporated in a non-intrusive way, but the object of an AD is to be noticed by potential viewers, so by definition ADs are going to detract from how nice the webpage looks. I think there's also a psychological effect, since seeing a clean webpage without ADs gives the viewer a good first impression. I often feel that people do not take this into consideration when placing ADs on their webpages, since the extra revenue gained from those viewers who would have stayed were ADs not on the webpage may be significant.